# Rpc work Queue Exceeded

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I am trying to make rpc calls to an Rpc Interface "listunspent". So i get this Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT. I checked the bitcoin node debug file and saw the error message "Depth queue work exceeded". I have added this option rpcworkqueue= settings to the bitcoin.conf file.

Here is my bitcoin.conf file

```
prune=550 port=8333 rpcworkqueue=1000 rpcuser=user rpcpassword=userpass zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:29000 zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:29000 zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:29000 zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:29000
```

The following is the error response i get while trying to make rpc calls from my node app

```
{
"status": 500,
"error": {
    "name": "RequestError",
    "message": "Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT",
    "cause": {
        "code": "ESOCKETTIMEDOUT",
        "connect": false
    },
    "error": {
        "code": "ESOCKETTIMEDOUT",
        "connect": false
    },
    "options": {
        "auth": {
            "user": "user",
            "pass": "userpass"
        },
        "uri": "/",
        "baseUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8332",
        "timeout": 30,
        "json": true,
        "body": {
            "method": "listunspent",
            "params": {},
            "jsonrpc": 1,
            "id": "rpc-bitcoin"
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "simple": true,
        "resolveWithFullResponse": false,
        "transform2xxOnly": false
    }
}
```

}

Any help to solve this?